# Binary Tree -- Finding the number of nodes k depth

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

The following function operates on a binary tree. The function will take in a pointer to the root of the tree and a non negative int k. It should return the number of nodes k depth from the root.

```
struct treenode {
  int data;
  struct treenode* left;
  struct treenode* right;
}

int numNodesHeightK(struct treenode* root, int k){
  if(root == NULL) return 0; //if the tree is empty return 0
  if(k == 0) return 1; //if k = 0, then the root is the only node to return 

  //How does this statement work?
  return numNodesHeightK(root->left, k-1) + numNodesHeightK(root->right, k-1);
}
```

If someone could just explain the logic of the final statement. I'm not seeing how that line of code could return the correct depth.

Answer (score 3):

For each node, you want to add together the number of nodes at depth `k` from each of the subtrees.  That means traversing those subtrees for nodes that are depth `k-1` from their respective roots (the left and right subtrees of the current node).  When `k` gets to `0`, that means return `1` for that node - as it is depth `k` from the original root.

That last statement does exactly this operation - traversing first the left subtree, and then the right subtree, finding the number of nodes at depth `k` from the current node, adding them together, and then returning the result.

The algorithm is pretty straightforward - draw a test tree on paper and work through it step-by-step.  The logic should jump out at you pretty quickly.

Comment: I'd also point out that this is a *recursive* algorithm; being able to understand this example will help the OP understand many others.

Comment: +1 @Santa - good call.  The OP should check out "depth-first search" as well.

Answer (score 1):

The theory is that total number of nodes at a given depth (lets say depth = 5) is the same as the sum of the nodes of depth = 4 counted from the left-child and the right-child.  (because moving to a child already introduces a depth of 1).

So, lets find the number of Nodes at Depth 4 on the left-child:

```
numNodesHeightK(root->left, k-1)
```

and the number of Node at Depth 4 on the right-child:

```
numNodesHeightK(root->right, k-1)
```

and add them together to get the answer to get the number of nodes of Depth 5 from the our current node.

This alone doesn't solve the problem, it just broke it down into two simpler, smaller pieces.  The problem doesn't become completely solved until you ask for the number of nodes at Depth 0, which is obviously 1.  This is implemented in the function's *base case*:

```
if(k == 0) return 1; //if k = 0, then the root is the only node to return
```

And finally, you use the terms Height and Depth interchangeably, which gets confusing if you try to talk about going "down" or "up" the tree.  Pick one convention and stick to it.

Comment: Hi, what to do if we were to find the number of nodes in the tree "above" depth k (not including k), include node n if depth(n)<k.

Answer (score 1):

Just think of it recursively...

How many nodes are there in a subtree whose roor is `null`? `0`

```
if (root == NULL) return 0;
```

How many nodes are there under a node at a depth 0? `1` (the node itself).

```
if (k == 0) return 1;
```

How many nodes and subnodes has a tree otherwise? The nodes on the left side branch plus the nodes on the right side branch. Each branch is at a lower level.

```
// left side
numNodesHeightK(root->left, k-1) +
// right side 
numNodesHeightK(root->right, k-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To paint a picture of how this works...

Think like you have this group on a mission, and there are these tunnels that keep forking to two subtunnels. The goal is to find out after so many forks which subtunnel opens up into a cave. The distance between forks is one distance unit long.

Every time you reach a fork in the tunnel, the current group at that branch splits up in half and sends each half down both subtunnels.

Whenever the group has split up K times, they stop and look at the location. They then return to the surface, and every person tells whether he found a room k distance from the entry. If any of the subteams reach a dead end before distance k, they return back and say there was no room.

They add up the totals and report back to you.

The rooms are the nodes. The forks are the child nodes of each nodes. The subteams are the calls of your method on the stack.

Comment: In reality, the machine is actually sending one person who traverses back and forward through each node, in a zigzag fan pattern. If you had multiple threads, then it would be more like a team splitting up.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to understand that one line in isolation, because the function is recursive and that one line is *the one* that recurses.

But there are only three lines, so we can easily develop an understanding of the whole thing.

In order to count up the nodes at a given depth, it is necessary to traverse the tree up to that depth.

So that means we recursively take every left and right branch.

#### First Two Executable Lines

If we traverse down from a leaf node to a null node we just return 0. If we find outselves at the right depth, we can stop any pointless traversing further down in the tree and just return 1, because our instance of the recursive function has landed on a single node of the target depth. This line prevents us from traversing unnecessarily deeply, as well as providing the count for the branch we are on.

#### Last line

So finally, your last line. At each more shallow level it is necessary to descend deeper into the tree, and in a recursive implementation that is done by calling a new instance of the function for each branch of the tree.  This line may be executed again by the called instance, until the call graph itself cumulatively mirrors the actual tree, and each level returns increasingly larger consolidated sums to the previous levels, which finally returns a single potentially quite large number from the single instance at the top node.